# How can i dynamically reduce deep JS objects with arrays to a JS object without arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, merge

I'm having an array of objects with an id as key for each object. Each object represents a navigation list for the id.

I need to merge all navigation lists to one big list in which the leafs contain the belonging ids.

The resulting object should contain no array but leafs that will be a list of the ids.

I already tried recursive solutions, lodash functions like merge and assign but I stuck with the deepness of the objects

The input JSON is e.g.:

```
[
  {
    "id0": [
      {
        "Topitem 1": [
          {
            "Subitem 1": [
              "Leaf 1"
            ]
          }, {
            "Subitem 2": [
              "Leaf 2"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Topitem 1": [
          {
            "Subitem 3": [
              "Leaf 1"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Topitem 2": [
          "Leaf 1",
          "Leaf 3"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Topitem 3": [
          {
            "Subitem 1": [
              {
                "SubSubitem 1": [
                  "Leaf 4"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id1": [
      "Leaf 5"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id2": [
      "Leaf 5"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id3": [
      {
        "Topitem 1": [
          "Leaf 1",
          {
            "Subitem 2": [
              "Leaf 2",
              "Leaf 3"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "Topitem 2": [
          "Leaf 1",
          "Leaf 2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id4": [
      "Leaf 5"
    ]
  }
]
```

The expected output is:

```
{
  "Topitem 1": {
    "Subitem 1": {
      "Leaf 1": ["id0"]
    },
    "Subitem 2": {
      "Leaf 2": ["id0","id3"],
      "Leaf 3": ["id3"]
    },
    "Subitem 3": {
      "Leaf 1": ["id0"]
    },
    "Leaf 1": ["id3"]
  },
  "Topitem 2": {
    "Leaf 1": ["id0","id3"],
    "Leaf 2": ["id0","id3"]
  },
  "Topitem 3": {
    "Subitem 1": {
      "SubSubitem 1": {
        "Leaf 4": ["id0"]
      }
    }
  },
  "Leaf5": ["id1","id2","id4"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach by using a distinct function for the first run, where you save the `id` for later collecting in an array and then use the recursive part for the nested objects/keys.

The main problem with the given data structure is that at the end, the arrays contains strings and not objects.

```js
function convert(array) {

    function iter(array, object, value) {
        array.forEach(o => {
            if (!o || typeof o !== 'object') {
                (object[o] = object[o] || []).push(value);
                return;
            }
            Object
                .entries(o)
                .forEach(([k, v]) => iter(v, object[k] = object[k] || {}, value));
        });
    }

    var result = {};
    array.forEach(o => Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => iter(v, result, k)));
    return result;
}

var data = [{ id0: [{ "Topitem 1": [{ "Subitem 1": ["Leaf 1"] }, { "Subitem 2": ["Leaf 2"] }] }, { "Topitem 1": [{ "Subitem 3": ["Leaf 1"] }] }, { "Topitem 2": ["Leaf 1", "Leaf 3"] }, { "Topitem 3": [{ "Subitem 1": [{ "SubSubitem 1": ["Leaf 4"] }] }] }] }, { id1: ["Leaf 5"] }, { id2: ["Leaf 5"] }, { id3: [{ "Topitem 1": ["Leaf 1", { "Subitem 2": ["Leaf 2", "Leaf 3"] }] }, { "Topitem 2": ["Leaf 1", "Leaf 2"] }] }, { id4: ["Leaf 5"] }];

console.log(convert(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) and [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). This solution works without recursion

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');
// const lodash = require('lodash');

const myObject = [{ id0: [{ 'Topitem 1': [{ 'Subitem 1': ['Leaf 1'] }, { 'Subitem 2': ['Leaf 2'] }] }, { 'Topitem 1': [{ 'Subitem 3': ['Leaf 1'] }] }, { 'Topitem 2': ['Leaf 1', 'Leaf 3'] }, { 'Topitem 3': [{ 'Subitem 1': [{ 'SubSubitem 1': ['Leaf 4'] }] }] }] }, { id1: ['Leaf 5'] }, { id2: ['Leaf 5'] }, { id3: [{ 'Topitem 1': ['Leaf 1', { 'Subitem 2': ['Leaf 2', 'Leaf 3'] }] }, { 'Topitem 2': ['Leaf 1', 'Leaf 2'] }] }, { id4: ['Leaf 5'] }];

const convert = (obj) => objectScan(['**'], {
  filterFn: ({ key, value, context }) => {
    if (typeof value !== 'string') {
      return;
    }
    const k = [...key.slice(2).filter((e) => typeof e === 'string'), value];
    const cur = lodash.get(context, k);
    if (cur === undefined) {
      lodash.set(context, k, [key[1]]);
    } else {
      cur.push(key[1]);
    }
  }
})(obj, {});

console.log(convert(myObject));
// => { 'Leaf 5': [ 'id4', 'id2', 'id1' ], 'Topitem 2': { 'Leaf 2': [ 'id3' ], 'Leaf 1': [ 'id3', 'id0' ], 'Leaf 3': [ 'id0' ] }, 'Topitem 1': { 'Subitem 2': { 'Leaf 3': [ 'id3' ], 'Leaf 2': [ 'id3', 'id0' ] }, 'Leaf 1': [ 'id3' ], 'Subitem 3': { 'Leaf 1': [ 'id0' ] }, 'Subitem 1': { 'Leaf 1': [ 'id0' ] } }, 'Topitem 3': { 'Subitem 1': { 'SubSubitem 1': { 'Leaf 4': [ 'id0' ] } } } }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
<script src="https://bundle.run/lodash@4.17.20"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

And here is a solution where we keep track of the stack and hence avoids using lodash. Unfortunately it is not as elegant as I would have liked it to be

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myObject = [{ id0: [{ 'Topitem 1': [{ 'Subitem 1': ['Leaf 1'] }, { 'Subitem 2': ['Leaf 2'] }] }, { 'Topitem 1': [{ 'Subitem 3': ['Leaf 1'] }] }, { 'Topitem 2': ['Leaf 1', 'Leaf 3'] }, { 'Topitem 3': [{ 'Subitem 1': [{ 'SubSubitem 1': ['Leaf 4'] }] }] }] }, { id1: ['Leaf 5'] }, { id2: ['Leaf 5'] }, { id3: [{ 'Topitem 1': ['Leaf 1', { 'Subitem 2': ['Leaf 2', 'Leaf 3'] }] }, { 'Topitem 2': ['Leaf 1', 'Leaf 2'] }] }, { id4: ['Leaf 5'] }];

const convert = (obj) => objectScan(['[*]*.**[*]', '[*]*.**.*'], {
  breakFn: ({
    matchedBy, key, value, property, context
  }) => {
    if (matchedBy.includes('[*]*.**.*')) {
      const cur = context[context.length - 1];
      if (!(property in cur)) {
        cur[property] = {};
      }
      context.push(cur[property]);
    } else if (typeof value === 'string') {
      const cur = context[context.length - 1];
      if (!(value in cur)) {
        cur[value] = [];
      }
      cur[value].push(key[1]);
    }
  },
  filterFn: ({ matchedBy, context }) => {
    if (matchedBy.includes('[*]*.**.*')) {
      context.pop();
    }
  }
})(obj, [{}])[0];

console.log(convert(myObject));
// => { 'Leaf 5': [ 'id4', 'id2', 'id1' ], 'Topitem 2': { 'Leaf 2': [ 'id3' ], 'Leaf 1': [ 'id3', 'id0' ], 'Leaf 3': [ 'id0' ] }, 'Topitem 1': { 'Subitem 2': { 'Leaf 3': [ 'id3' ], 'Leaf 2': [ 'id3', 'id0' ] }, 'Leaf 1': [ 'id3' ], 'Subitem 3': { 'Leaf 1': [ 'id0' ] }, 'Subitem 1': { 'Leaf 1': [ 'id0' ] } }, 'Topitem 3': { 'Subitem 1': { 'SubSubitem 1': { 'Leaf 4': [ 'id0' ] } } } }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)